# Make a responsive v-toolbar vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this code

```
<template>

<V-toolbar>

Button 1
Button 2 
.....
Button n

<\V-toolbar>
<\template>
```

And number of buttons will increase with scaling of application.

My question is how to make it responsive so that in a small screen these buttons can be viewed as a menu (...) .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the Vuetify breakpoint service, like below:

```
<v-toolbar>
    <v-menu bottom left v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs || $vuetify.breakpoint.sm">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
               dark
               icon
               v-bind="attrs"
               v-on="on">
               <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        Button 1
        Button 2 
        .....
        Button n
    </v-menu>
    <template v-else>
        Button 1
        Button 2 
        .....
        Button n
    </template>
</v-toolbar>
```

You can view more breakpoint options [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object).

Comment: Thankyou for this . One more thing , in v-toolbar i have many buttons which is exceeding the max width of laptop screen (only half of the extreme right button text is visible) . is there a way like i can have fixed width or more preferably i can have left and right navigations buttons ?

Comment: I can't think of an easy solution. A more complex one is to use the `extension` slot, it gives you more width and also a configurable height, where buttons can be stacked in two lines if needed. Another solution, is to use the `v-tabs` component width only `v-tab` instead of buttons. This component automatically add left and right navigation buttons if the width is exceeded.